# Questions about Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis

The statement of Lebesgue differentiation theorem  is:

For any locally integrable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$
f(x)=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy.\tag{*}
$$
for almost all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In the proof of Lebesgue differentiation theorem most of the books, for example "Stein, Elias M.; Shakarchi, Rami (2005). Real analysis.", says that:

It suffices to show that for each $\lambda>0$ the set

$$
\left\{x:\limsup_{r\to 0}\left|\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy-f(x)\right|>\lambda\right\}
$$
has measure zero. My questions are:

1) Why proofs don't show the existence of the limit in (*)?

2) According to the proofs something is proven more general by using $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$. Why the statement of the theorem never given by using $\limsup$?

Let
$$
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|dy=0.\tag{**}
$$

I read somewhere that $*\Leftrightarrow **$. The implication $**\Rightarrow *$ is trivial but how can we prove that $*\Rightarrow **$.

My last question is how can we generalize (**) to the case 
$$
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|^p dy=0, \qquad p>1
$$ 
for almost all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: for $\ast$ implies $\ast\ast$ see for example Stein's book on singular intervals (first chapter; it is basically an approximation argument using separability). For a general version of $\ast\ast$ see for instance the first chapter of Evans and Gariepy. It is the same argument, follows from $\ast\ast$.

Comment: @deb Your comment is very useful, thank you very much. What do you think about my other questions 1) and 2)?

Comment: If the lim sup of a non negative sequence of numbers is zero, then, it equals the lim inf and the limit exists.